# problem with loading packages to texmaker using miktex

Tags: packages, miktex

I get the following errors when trying to build:

Line: `\documentclass[a4paper, english]{scrartcl}`

Log error:

> ```
>  ! LaTeX Error: File `scrartcl.cls' not found.
>  Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
>  or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)
>  Enter file name:
>  ! Emergency stop.
> ```

If I change the line to `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}` it works, but falls on the next line:
`\usepackage{natbib}`

Logerror:

> ```
>  ! LaTeX Error: File `natbib.sty' not found.
>  Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
>  or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
>  Enter file name:
>  ! Emergency stop.
> ```

In my MikTeX package manager I see `koma-script` is installed and when I try to add `natbib`, I get

> ```
>  MiKTeX Problem Report
>  Message: Couldn't connect to server
>  Data: 
>  Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\CurlWebSession.cpp
>  Line: 337
>  MiKTeX: 2.9
>  OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, build 15063
>  Invokers: non-existing
>  SystemAdmin: no
>  PowerUser: no
>  Root0: C:\Users\TamarPC\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
>  Root1: C:\Users\TamarPC\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
>  Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
>  Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
>  UserInstall: C:\Users\TamarPC\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
>  UserConfig: C:\Users\TamarPC\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
>  UserData: C:\Users\TamarPC\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
>  CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
>  CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
>  CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
> ```

what's going on here?

Comment: Can you run MikTeX's Update tool? Can you change the repository in the 'Package Manager'?

Comment: Tried to run MikTeX's Update and got the error: "Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect". What should I change my repository to?

Comment: I reinstalled the MikTeX and Texmaker and used the 32bit version. I don't know if there was some problem with the installation or it is infect the 32 vs 64, but it is working now. Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because reinstalling solves the issue (see comments).

Comment: Just now I upgrade my 64-bit MikTeX withou any problem.